# How to get two lines of text fixed at positions?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

How can I achieve from this

[image]

to this

[image]

when resizing the browser.
For your information, these are the lines of lyrics with chords. I want to achieve exact same fixed position of chords above lyrics to make it responsive. I am using HTML, CSS.
Anybody, please help.

```css
.lines {
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.lyrics,.notes {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(45, 45, 45);
    font-weight: 600;
}

.lines>span:first-child:after {
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre-line;
}

.notes {
    color: rgb(0, 150, 0);
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
}
```

```html
<div class="lines">
        <span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="notes">G</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="notes">Em</span></span>
        <span class="lyrics">Well, I found a girl, beautiful and sweet</span>
        </div>

        <div class="lines">
        <span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="notes">C</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="notes">D</span></span>
        <span class="lyrics">Oh, I never knew you were the someone waiting for me</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: you need to use a table element.  I have done here this kind of stuff before...

Comment: Kindly add what you've tried so far (both the HTML and the CSS).

Comment: Yes, I have added the HTML and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way...

```js
(()=>  // IIFE code on load for lyrics presentation
  {
  const rgxCut   = /(?=\[)|(?<=\])/;

  document.querySelectorAll('div.lyrics p').forEach( pLine =>
    {
    let newP = pLine.textContent
    .replaceAll('] [',']&emsp;[')
    .split(rgxCut)
    .map( el =>
      {
      if (el[0]!=='[') return el
      let chord = el.substring(1,el.length-1)
      return `<span class="chord" data-chord="${chord}"></span>`
      })
    pLine.innerHTML = newP.join('')
    })
  }
)()
```

```css
/* --- for testing --- */
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 20px;
  }
.reSizable {
  resize   : both;
  overflow : scroll;
  padding  : .5em;
  border   : 1px solid orange;
  }
/* ------------------- */

div.lyrics p  {
  line-height : 2.5em;
  }
div.lyrics p span[data-chord] {
  position : relative
  }
div.lyrics p span[data-chord]::after {
  position   : absolute;
  top         : -1.2em;
  left        : -.1em;
  line-height : 1.2em;
  padding     : 0 .2em;
  font-size   : .9em;
  color       : darkgreen;
  background  : lightgrey;  
  content     : attr(data-chord);
  }
```

```html
<div class="reSizable">

    <div class="lyrics">
      <p>Well, I found a [G]girl, beauti[Em]full and sweet</p>
      <p>Oh, I never [C]knew you where the someone waiting for [D]me</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Well, this is working well but it will become a lot difficult to write the full song in this way. Can it be achieved through the  HTML which I attached to ques.?

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA Well, we can't say that you are a very cooperative interlocutor.... Is the change made befitting your highness?

Comment: wow, what a great solution!!

Comment: @MisterJojo, you have done a really great job. Thanks!